# What is negation of the statement - Task T has lower bound of Ω(g(n))

Tags: performance, algorithm

It is given that a certain computation has a performance lowerbound of Ω(g(n)) on an input size n. What would be the negation of this statement ? I.e what would be the statement which corresponds to the above statement being false.

My intuition says -
There exists an algorithm using which we can do the computation in O(g(n)).

I am confused if it should be Big-O or small-o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be small o.

```
Ω(g(n)) [intersection] O(g(n)) = Theta(g(n))
```

So, the fact that it is `Ω(g(n))` is not contradicting `O(g(n))`.

On the other hand, `o(g(n)) = O(g(n)) \ Theta(g(n))`

And thus:

```
Ω(g(n)) [intersection] o(g(n)) =  Ω(g(n)) [intersection] (O(g(n)) \ Theta(g(n)))
= Theta(g(n)) \ Theta(g(n)) = {}
```

So, the set that is the intersection of `o(g(n))` and `Ω(g(n))` is an empty set - it means if some function is in `o(g(n))`, it cannot be in `Ω(g(n))`.

Comment: The fact alone that the intersection of o(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)) is empty is not enough to say that being o(g(n)) is the opposite of being in Ω(g(n)), isn't it?

Comment: @effeffe It is sufficient to contradict f(n) is in Ω(g(n)) by saying f(n) is in o(g(n)). If you want it to be iff - you should also say that `Ω(g(n)) U o(g(n)) = {all functions}` - which is true, but I don't think that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: That's what I meant (I should have been more accurate with my comment, sorry), relying on the two sets being disjoint is valid in this specific case just because their union is the set of all functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ω(g(n)) means *at least g(n)*. The negation is *it's not true that we need at least g(n)*, which means that we can do better than g(n), so the negation is that the task can be done in o(g(n)).

Comment: So, one clarification. If a lower bound is given as Ω(g(n)) , it would imply that even the best case input would need more than that time. And negation would mean, that even worst case input would need less than that time -  the o(g(n)) .

Comment: Not necessarily "more", that would be ω(g(n)).